# wordpress $query_string

Tags: wordpress, querystringparameter

$query_String outputs blank in the attached code. 
I thought wp-load would populate the $query_string variable as part of the initialization for me and I could straight output its value once I define it as global, but I must be missing something somewhere

```
<?php
//test url mysite.com/thissnippet.php?name=John
include 'wp-load.php';
global $query_string;
echo "querystring is " ;
echo $query_string;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to echo the query string using the superglobal $_GET.

```
echo $_GET['name'];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
//test url mysite.com/thissnippet.php?name=John
include 'wp-load.php';
global $query_string;
$query_string = $_GET['name'];
echo "querystring is $query_string";

?>
```

Comment: I do not understand this answer. what would including wp_load.php and declaring the known WP variable $query_string as global do for me? your last two lines would do equally good. I thought, wp internal machanisms populate the $query_string variable for me so that I don't have to use a server variable ( $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] to find that out... That's what I was wondering in my org. question...